# On Stripe, how can I link existing credit card to new customer?

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a credit card on Stripe with id `card_XXXXXX` and I want to create a new Stripe customer and add this card to this customer.

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

P.

Comment: To whomever downvoted my question I would like to know the reason why, in order to make it better next time. So, if you are kind enough to leave a comment, I would appreciate.

Comment: Share some code indicating what you've tried.  You don't even mention what language you are working with which makes it hard to answer your question.

Comment: @Dhaulagiri Thanks for this comment, but probably you don't know Stripe. IMHO, if I were in your shoes I wouldn't downvote a question just because I do not know the subject matter. This question is addressed to people who know Stripe well. Stripe has API for many languages and works exactly the same for all of them. I posted the same question on Stripe IRC channel and they replied correctly within in 30 seconds. Without any further comments on my side. I will post my findings soon below.

Comment: I didn't downvote your question and I have used Stripe many times.  I was just trying to help you make your question more clear so that you could get an answer more quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

A card belongs to a customer.

https://stripe.com/docs/api#update_card
This shows the fields of a card that can be updated:

**address_city** optional
**address_country** optional
**address_line1** optional
**address_line2** optional
**address_state** optional
**address_zip** optional
**exp_month** optional
**exp_year** optional
**name** optional

Think about it in a real world scenario -
Why would MY credit card ever be (legally) given to you?

Comment: Your answer is correct. However,your explanation why Stripe does not allow that,is not aligned with the fact that you can create a card and charge it WITHOUT attaching it to any customer.I wouldn't consider that a real world scenario either,but it IS supported by Stripe.BTW,I would like to be able to do that exactly for this reason.I have an e-shop integration case in which the e-shop integrates with Stripe without creating a customer, and for some reason, that I cannot explain here, I want to create the customer for this charge/cc.(I will accept your answer).